# absolute layout or any alternative?

Tags: android

I have to write a complex layout that is built from many ImageViews.
Think about a car...I have an image for the car background and then an image for every car component...let's say doors, tyres, lights and I have just to show/hide them in response to the status of the car.

For example, I have two different images for the car doors, open or close and I have to show the "open door bitmap" if the door is open and the "close door" viceversa.
So I have to position every bitmap at a particular position.

I'm thinking which is the best layout to use. 
The easier choice would be an AbsoluteLayout but using it will be a nightmare scale the app to different resolutions.
Actually my app is targeted to tablet devices.

I have other choices?

Comment: I think you will have to draw all that using a raw view and a Canvas.

Comment: BTW - how will you handle different resolutions?  Will your images scale or do you have multiple versions of the same image?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not using a complex layout and using a [Canvas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html) instead. This way your drawing is much more efficient.  It will be a little harder, but I don't think you will regret putting in the extra work for what you get out of it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RelativeLayout and position the images relative to each other.  For example, if you have two images side-by-side, you can use

```
android:layout_toLeftOf
```

to position one image just to the left of the other.  You can do this for above, below, left or right.